# retrieve the data from MySQL database, in dictionary format in python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
def Network():

    dict = {'CISCO' : 'NEXUS', 'JUNIPER' : 'JUNO', 'Alcatel' : 'Alc' }


    #len(dict)
    return (dict)



def db_store(variable):
    con = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","fs_company" )
    cur = con.cursor()
    for key,value in variable.items():
        cur.execute('''INSERT into google (name, company) values (%s, %s)''', (key, value))
        con.commit()
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM google""")
    variable = cur.fetchall()
    #print variable



variable = Network()
db_store(variable)
```

I have above code to store the data to mysql database, I want to retrieve the data from database in dictionary format. need help for the same

Comment: What did you try so far? A hint. When working with SQLite dont insert your values with `%s`. That could leed to formatting problems. Replace them by `?`, then the databse does the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing only one line. You can convert *variable* into dict like this:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM google""")
out = cur.fetchall()
variable = {key:val for key,val in out}
print(variable)
```